Unable to run flutter project: > A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Applications/flutter/bin/flutter''
I upgraded Android Studio on my Mac to the latest JellyFish version but now I can't run one of my flutter projects.
It appears related to the build gradle but not sure where.
Nothing seems to have changed. I checked/tried:

I have the flutter SDK is set in Android Studio settings.
Flutter doctor is all updated and fine.
Updated pubspec, restarted.

The error:


I ended up running "flutter create ." then "flutter clean" and "flutter pub get" and restarting and it worked...

This answer helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64054311/25045168
Note that the commands must be executed from android folder

Thanks, I didn't get a chance to try, as I fixed it by running "flutter create .", "flutter clean" "flutter pub get"

Not an answer, should have been mentioned duplicate

Have you tried "pod deintegrate" and "pod install --repo-update"?
